# What is the real difference between ACTION_GET_CONTENT and ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT?

Tags: android

I'm having a hard time understanding the difference between `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` and `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` intents **when they are used to open an openable document**. If I am supporting Andriod before KitKat, which does not support `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, should I just settle with `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`?

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html#client) says this:

> [`ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT) is not intended to be a replacement for
>   [`ACTION_GET_CONTENT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_GET_CONTENT). The one you should use depends on the needs of
>   your app:
>
> - Use [`ACTION_GET_CONTENT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_GET_CONTENT) if you want your app to simply read/import
>     data. With this approach, the app imports a copy of the data, such as
>     an image file.
> - Use [`ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT) if you want your app to have
>     long term, persistent access to documents owned by a document
>     provider. An example would be a photo-editing app that lets users edit
>     images stored in a document provider.

Doesn't `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` also use document providers in KitKat? What would prevent me from having "long term, persistent access" and what exactly does that mean?

Basically, what is the difference between the following two snippets?

**ACTION_GET_CONTENT**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("*/*");
```

**ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
intent.setType("*/*");
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

> Doesn't ACTION_GET_CONTENT also use document providers in KitKat?

Not necessarily. That depends on the implementation of the app that is publishing the content. Also note that `DocumentProvider` is a specific type of `ContentProvider`.

> What would prevent me from having "long term, persistent access"

The `Uri` that you get back from `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` may have a temporary permission grant with it for your app, to be able to read and/or write the content. That grant will eventually lapse (e.g., when your process terminates). So, for example, saving the `Uri` as a string in a database may be pointless.

Part of the Storage Access Framework includes the concept that a provider of content can offer permission grants that can last for an extended period ("long-term, persistent"). While there's nothing stopping an app from offering such persistent permissions with `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` on API Level 19+, they will be more common with `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`.

> Basically, what is the difference between the following two snippets?

The user experience will be somewhat different, as `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` provides a standardized file explorer-style interface, whereas `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` is a traditional chooser dialog, followed by some app-specific UI.

From your standpoint as a consumer of this content, `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` is if you want to use the content now; `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` is if you want to use the content now and later.

**Edit:** Links to documentation:

[ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT)

[ACTION_GET_CONTENT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_GET_CONTENT)

From the [Common Intents example for opening a specific type of file](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#OpenFile):

> Instead of retrieving a copy of a file that you must import to your app (by using the ACTION_GET_CONTENT action), when running on Android 4.4 or higher, you can instead request to open a file that's managed by another app by using the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT action and specifying a MIME type. To also allow the user to instead create a new document that your app can write to, use the ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT action instead. For example, instead of selecting from existing PDF documents, the ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT intent allows users to select where they'd like to create a new document (within another app that manages the document's storage)—your app then receives the URI location of where it can write the new document.
>
> Whereas the intent delivered to your onActivityResult() method from the ACTION_GET_CONTENT action may return a URI of any type, the result intent from ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT and ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT always specify the chosen file as a content: URI that's backed by a DocumentsProvider. You can open the file with openFileDescriptor() and query its details using columns from DocumentsContract.Document.

Comment: In my experience, there is never a chooser dialog. The two actions result in the same fullscreen UI. It is like a file explorer, but you can also choose to slide out a left drawer full of app icons. The only difference when using each action is this list of apps on the left. When I pass image MIME types, GET_CONTENT allows me to explore not only my folders like downloads, but also has an entry on a slide out left drawer for Google Photos, Dropbox, etc. If I use OPEN_DOCUMENT, I get the exact same UI, there just are no apps in the left drawer willing to serve me content other than Google Drive.

Comment: @Stephen: "there is never a chooser dialog" -- `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` will have one on Android 4.3 and older. "The only difference when using each action is this list of apps on the left" -- some apps support one of the actions, some support the other. Ideally, an app like Dropbox would support `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` on Android 4.4+, falling back to supporting `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` on Android 4.3 and lower.

Comment: I just installed my application on a 4.3 device and you are correct! A "picker" did show up rather than the "file explorer" type interface. Thanks for the help! By the way, love your books. I've been subscribed for years.

Comment: @Stephen: Thanks for the kind words!