# Multiple MIME types pdf and image

Tags: android, kotlin, mime-types

From file chooser I want to allow choose only pdf and images, is it possible to do in Android? I tried do same things from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698050/multiple-mime-types-in-android), but I don't know why, file manager allow choose any file.

```
 override fun createIntent(context: Context, input: Array<String>?): Intent {
        val mimeTypes = arrayListOf("image/*", "application/pdf")
        return Intent().apply {
            type = "*/*"
            action = Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT
            addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes)
        }
    }
```

Comment: `From file manager I want ....`. No. From `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late but I am looking for the same solution currently and I found this: [Passing Multiple Mime Types to ActivityResultLauncher.launch()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66813551/passing-multiple-mime-types-to-activityresultlauncher-launch)
It solved my problem like a charm. Hope it's helpful for people ran into this problem in the future.

Comment: If your answer doesn't contain codes, please use "comment" instead.