# Can't read image path from room in different fragment

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments, image-processing, android-room, android-permissions

I can choose image from gallery and save it's Uri path to room db in fragment 1. 
While the app is still running, it's ok to get the image Uri and show it in fragment 2.

**Problem**
After close the app and restart it, fragment 2 will crash.

I found below post looks better to solve permission issue. 
But I'm not sure how to implement it in `onActivityResult` (original answer is in Java). 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29588566/16430096

Below is my `onActiviyResult` code

```
    var selectedImage: Uri? = null


    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        if (requestCode == IMAGE_PICK_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            selectedImage = data?.data
            imageView.setImageURI(selectedImage)
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            val takeFlags = data?.flags?.and(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
            val resolver = activity?.contentResolver

            //TODO: What should I do here?
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution from below post. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36182357/16430096

There's no need to change `onActivityResult`, just use `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` like below. 
Like the post describe, `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` provide longer permission  even after the app is closed.

Using `Intent.ACTION_PICK` will only get temporary permission which will lead to `SecurityException` after restart the app.

```
private fun pickImageFromGallery() {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT)
    intent.type = "image/*"
    if (intent.resolveActivity(requireActivity().packageManager) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "select file"), IMAGE_PICK_CODE)
    }
}
```