# Display image from content:// URI without opening file picker

Tags: android, kotlin, android-image, android-file, android-storage

As part of my app, users can select images from their device and I store the URLs to these in my database. Then, elsewhere in the app, I need to display those images.

I am getting the image URI through `Intent.ACTION_PICK`:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
intent.type = "image/*"
imagePickerAction = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { uri: Uri? ->
    if (uri != null) {
        val uriString = uri.toString()
        saveToDatabase(uriString)
    }
}
```

This results in a URI string like `content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A1000000038`.

I am able to show the image using `ImageView.setImageURI` at this point.

But later on, when I fetch the URI from the database and try to use `setImageURI` again, I get this error:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider from ProcessRecord{cdd4e32 10499:com.skamz.shadercam/u0a160} (pid=10499, uid=10160) requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs

I have also tried following the docs here https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#open:

```
private fun getBitmapFromUri(uri: Uri): Bitmap {
    val parcelFileDescriptor: ParcelFileDescriptor? =
        contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(uri, "r")
    if (parcelFileDescriptor == null) {
        return bitmapFromUri(contentResolver, Uri.parse(TextureOverlayShaderData.defaultImageUrl))
    }
    val fileDescriptor: FileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.fileDescriptor
    val image: Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor)
    parcelFileDescriptor.close()
    return image
}
```

This returns a bitmap, which I then pass into `ImageView.bitmapFromUri`. Unfortunately, this produces the same error, this time coming from `contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(uri, "r")`

Comment: You need to read Commonsware's blog.

Comment: Or you could use this link to understand https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36182134/what-is-the-real-difference-between-action-get-content-and-action-open-document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I fetch the URI from the database

That's not an option with `ACTION_PICK`. You cannot reliably persist a `Uri` that you received from `ACTION_PICK` and use it again later. [Your access rights to the content are short-lived](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/08/08/uri-access-lifetime-still-shorter-than-you-might-think.html).

If you switch to `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` *and* use `takePersistableUriPermissions()` on a `ContentResolver` when you get the `Uri` in `onActivityResult()`, you can safely persist that `Uri`. You might still run into problems using it later — for example, the user could delete the image that the `Uri` points to — but you will not encounter the access problem that you are seeing here.